# How to change background in CalendarExtender for selected dates?

Tags: asp.net, ajax

I want to change background color for holiday list in Ajax CalendarExtender 
is it possible not to asp:calendar only for ajax:calendarextender

Comment: Holidays means Sundays would be highlighted?

Comment: holiday mean non working day it may be saturday,sunday or other day like monday etc, all holidaysdates -comming from database

Comment: May be these links can help you:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9370969/jquery-datepicker-highlight-holidays

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19395558/highlight-disable-specific-days-in-jquery-ui-datepicker
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9370969/jquery-datepicker-highlight-holidays
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2735207/javascript-jquery-datepicker-simple-highlighting-of-specific-days-who-can-he

Comment: friends i am looking for ajax calendarextender with c# code